# Who proved that $l^1$ and $L^1[0,1]$ are not isomorphic?

Tags: reference-request, banach-spaces

$l^1$ has the Schur property (every weakly convergent sequence is norm convergent) and $L^1[0,1]$ does not, so the two spaces cannot be isomorphic.

Is this folklore, or is it credited to someone? (Also I wonder whether the original proof of non-isomorphism was this one.)

Edit: to clear up any confusion, I am asking about the nonexistence of an isomorphism, not the nonexistence of an isometric isomorphism (which is basic, as pointed out in the comments).

Edit 2: the comment section seems to have degenerated into attempts to find alternate proofs of this fact (and debate over common misconceptions, such as whether a Banach space which is isomorphic to a dual space must itself be a dual space). That's great, although I still think the Schur property argument is the easiest one. However, this was not my question. Who first proved this?

Comment: Who noticed first that $\ell^1\simeq c_0^*$? Probably the same person.

Comment: Are you asking for who was the first one to prove non-isomorphism or for who was the first one to give this argument?

Comment: @Wojowu: the question in the title is my main question, although I am also curious as to whether this was the argument that was originally used.

Comment: @UriBader: I don't see why --- $l^1 \cong c_0^*$ is completely trivial, but you need to have the concept of the Schur property to prove non-isomorphism. Unless there is another, easier proof I don't know?

Comment: Another proof: $l^1$ has the Radon-Nikodym property, $L_1[0,1]$ does not.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar: that is true, good point.

Comment: Unit ball in $L^1$ does not have extreme points, thus $L^1$ is not conjugate to any space by Krein-Milman theorem (plus Banach-Alaoglu.) All this seems pretty basic and old.

Comment: I came here to say what Fedor Petrov said... I find this the easiest argument, But I doubt that was the original one. This shows that $L^1$ and $\ell^1$ are not isomorphic and that $L^1$ is not a dual space in the same instance.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: The question is about isomorphism, not isometric isomorphism.

Comment: For instance, I found [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=1u_2uQeOOHMC&pg=PA170&lpg=PA170&dq=not+a+dual+banach+space+isomorphic+to+a+dual+space&source=bl&ots=QcQZ0YO-Z4&sig=JI1SSK8CAWCFF0EEPoQ-CeRLqyw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5wP_mxb7MAhUJNSYKHSmpC54Q6AEIWDAI#v=onepage&q=not%20a%20dual%20banach%20space%20isomorphic%20to%20a%20dual%20space&f=false) a cute example of a Banach space which is isomorphic to $l^\infty$ but which is not a dual space.

Comment: Nik Weaver, we simply note that if a space is isomorphic (need not be isometric) to a dual space then every closed bounded convex set in it, including its ball, will have extreme points.

Comment: @NikWeaver ... A separable Banach space isomorphic (even if not isomorphic) to a dual space still has that extreme point property: any closed bounded convex set has lots of extreme points.  But the unit ball of $L^1$ has no extreme points, so...  But Uri: don't you need to say "separable" for this?

Comment: Nik, It works also for linear isomorphism: unit ball in any equivalent norm of the dual space is weakly star compact, right?

Comment: @Gerald, just as much as separability is needed in Banach-Alaoglu and Krein-Milman :)

Comment: For example, there is a closed bounded convex set in $L^\infty$ with no extreme points.  Indeed, there is such a set isometric to the unit ball of $L^1$.  But all we need in this problem is the separable case: and indeed a separable dual space does have the Krein-Milman property that every closed bounded convex set is the closed convex hull of its extreme points.

Comment: Uri and Fedor, you are wrong. Look at the link I provided (the "cute example"). It's a simple example of a Banach space which is isomorphic to $l^\infty$ but whose unit ball has no extreme points.

Comment: @Edgar, Nik, yes, you are right, sorry. Separability is important here. I hate to be stupid in public...

Comment: Well, separability (of the dual) is another essential property we should require, but fortunately it holds for $\ell^1=c_0^*$, and for $L^1[0,1]$ too. So, this argument probably does not generalize to non-separable $L_1$'s, but works for the initial question.

Comment: Yes, it looks correct. I didn't know that isomorphisms of separable Banach spaces preserve the extreme point property, that is interesting.

Comment: @NikWeaver, the cute example you refer to is indeed cute, but is not completely correct: the unit ball has many extreme points, namely all the elements $x \in \ell^\infty$ such that $|x_n|=\frac 1 2$ for all $n$. But this is still cute, because the closed convex hull of these extreme points is strictly smaller than the unit ball.

Comment: @MikaeldelaSalle: You're right! I didn't notice that.

Comment: Let $K$ be a compact Hausdorff space and let $p$ be a point in $K$ that is not isolated.  Then the continuous functions on $K$ that vanish at $p$ is a codimension one subspace of $C(K)$ whose unit ball has no extreme point. So any $C(K)$ that is isomorphic to its hyperplanes can be equivalently renormed so that its unit ball has no extreme point. $L_-\infty$ falls into this category. What is extraordinary is that, as Jerry pointed out, for any equivalent renorming of a separable conjugate space, the unit ball is the closed convex hull of its extreme points.

Comment: If you want to take care of the remaining infinite dimensional $C(K)$ spaces, observe that if the unit ball of $X$ has no extreme point, then neither does the unit ball of $X\oplus_\infty {\cal R}$.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This result was already published in the French (1932) edition of Banach's book "Theory of Linear Operations" (I do not know whether it was published in the Polish (1931) edition). On page 245 in the table you see two reasons why the spaces $\ell_1$ and $L_1(0,1)$ have different linear dimension:

1. Schur property for $\ell_1$ and no Schur property for $L_1$.
2. The fact that $\ell_1$ is isomorphically embeddable into each of its infinite dimensional subspaces and the same is not true for $L_1$.

Apparently for both statements about $L_1$ Banach means that they follow from the Khinchin's inequality (1923), but I did not find the corresponding place in the book.

Comment: Great. Just what I was looking for!

Comment: @NikWeaver To complement Mikhail's answer, let me point out that in the Polish edition of Banach's book on p. 183 the above argument is also used. See http://kielich.amu.edu.pl/Stefan_Banach/pdf/teoria-operacji-pol/08.pdf

If you need a direct translation, I am happy to make you one.

Comment: @TomekKania: Thank you, I think I can see it. In number 4, right?

Comment: @NikWeaver, yes :-)

Comment: I am curious - Schur's paper on the "Schur property" appeared in 1921. Did he not use it for this result? (Schur's paper is quite long, so I am a little worried about actually reading it...)

Comment: @Igor Rivin I looked through the paper of Schur, it looks like it concerns summability of series and not comparison of $\ell_1$ and $L_1$ as Banach spaces, although to be sure in this, the paper should be checked by a person with better knowledge of German. The paper is available online at: https://eudml.org/doc/149500